# Why is the potential on an infintie conductor near a point charge equal to 0?

Tags: electromagnetism

In Griffiths' *Electrodynamics* 4th ed., chapter 2, section 2, subsection 1, "The Classic Image Problem", we imagine an infinite conducting plane and a point charge not on the plane.  In this setup he claims that the potential on the plane is 0 and I can reproduce the argument for this:

The potential at infinity is 0, and a conducting surface is an equipotential.

However, the charge density on the conductor varies--indeed it increases as you approach the point on the plane nearest the charge.  So $\nabla^2V = -\rho/\epsilon_0 \ne 0$ therefore $V\ne 0$.

I guess maybe there were assumptions which went into Poisson's equation.  I could imagine the plane is not differentiable since there's a discontinuity in the field ... but that kind of thing often doesn't stop a physicist, we can usually imagine the plane has a little thickness or something like that.

So I dunno ... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I discovered the source of my error.  It comes down to my recurring lack of intuition for energy in general and potential energy in this case.  I kept intuitively thinking that if the charge distribution, and therefore the electric field, varies, then the potential energy can't be constant.  But the important point to realize is that the potential energy can be identified with the work *in the direction of motion* needed to bring a charge in from infinity.  Here because the conductor is a flat plane, the field is orthogonal to the direction of motion.  So although the field varies and your arms may get tired trying to keep the particle from flying away from the conductor as you get close to the point charge, this exertion (force) doesn't factor into the quantity we define as work.

Answer (score 0):

Make the conducting plane finite thickness.  Then, the field inside has to be zero.  You can go through this zero field region all the way to infinity.  Thus, the conductor is at $V=0$.  Since this argument didn't depend on the thickness of the slab, the potential will remain zero as you take the limit to zero thickness.